# Change font using Win2D drawtext

Tags: c#, fonts, draw, win2d

Does anyone know how to change the default font using win2d drawtext method?
I need it to be a monospaced font like Courier New.

args.DrawingSession.DrawText("User : " + UNAME, 10, 350,Colors.White);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the answer I was looking for. I stumbled upon it earlier.

```
 args.DrawingSession.DrawText(Math.Round(percent * 100,1) + "%", Convert.ToSingle(pointX + 10), Convert.ToSingle(pointY), Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255), new CanvasTextFormat(){FontSize = 10 });


**new CanvasTextFormat(){FontSize = 10 }**
```

Answer (score 0):

Font is specified (along with other formatting information) by the CanvasTextFormat type.  Use one of the many DrawText overloads that takes a text format parameter.